# Rails app with Boostrap not mobile response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, frontend

After adding the viewport meta tag, my app still is not mobile responsive. I am using bootstrap as well. Is there any fix?

application.html.erb

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>gustoHop</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%#= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <!-- Uncomment if you import CSS in app/javascript/packs/application.js -->
    <!-- <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
    </style> -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('gustoHop-favicon.png') %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render "shared/footer" %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you inspect that page are there any errors?  Missing files or incorrect file paths, anything like that?

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-I got the following errors. not sure if these are related: 
 extension://nndknepjnldbdbepjfgmncbggmopgden/client/dist2/js/dm_content_script.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
localhost/:1  and also:    Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.